# Is there a tool to generate OCMOD files?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, ocmod

I'm starting to get into customizing OC3 for my needs, and see the benefit of putting extensions in OCMOD files.

I assume people test and debug their code by temporarily rewriting the core files, and only write the OCMODs after the extension is ready.

Given an original file and a version with a customized script or modification, is there a tool to compare them and generate the OCMOD xml automatically? (maybe based on diff)

Or extension developers do that manually?

Answer (score 2):

Try this repository in github. it automatically generates install.xml :

https://github.com/ataul/ocmod_generator

Answer (score 1):

There are no tools available for OCMOD.

Extension Developers do that manually.